# How to convert 24 hours format to 12 hours format in soql date function hour_in_day

Tags: apex, soql

I have a soql query in which I'm retrieving the hour of the day which is in `24 hour` format I want that to converted into `12 hour` format while retrieving from soql query.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The date function I'm using is `HOUR_IN_DAY(CreatedDate)`

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: Do you want in apex?

Comment: Hi Ratan, That will be great if I get this in apex.But do we have any specific function to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try with this code in your developer console.**

```
for(Account obj : [SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM Account LIMIT 20]){
    Datetime myDateTime = obj.CreatedDate;
    String dtConverted = myDateTime.format('MM/dd/yyyy h a');
    system.debug('======'+dtConverted);
}
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: you are simply awesome. Thank you very much Ratan.

Comment: Most welcome @prasanthcheenu